# Is there a name for the "big operators" like summation and product notation?

Tags: notation

There are "big operators" like $\sum$, $\prod$, $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$ to describe a repeated application of a certain operator on some expression. For example, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 = 0^2 + 1^2 + \ldots + (n-1)^2 + n^2$.

Is there a general name for these operators?

Comment: Summing (resp. Union, Intersecting, Multiplying) over a family of sets is sometimes used. For infinite unions, Wikipedia calls this an "infinitary union", though I've never heard of that term. In the finite case, each of these are just shorthand for sum, product, union and intersection. The infinite case is where the definitions need more precision.

Answer (score 1):

They are sometimes called "large operators".  E.g. [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=coTdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=%22large+operators%22+latex&source=bl&ots=UOVAHp0EB5&sig=ACfU3U1Dj8Vhg_iSYIE5gCWeC9BWPB5l4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRofGgkInnAhUJCawKHQbWB7kQ6AEwDXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22large%20operators%22%20latex&f=false)